# Localization - How do we manage multilingual, multi-environment on multiple domains?

Tags: localization, multi-environment, language, multi-domain

I read this [KB article](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/localization) about localization though, the examples are for sub-folders.

I'm wondering how to handle the same concept but, for different language based domains e.g.

- example.com
- example.mx
- example.es

Currently I'm not sure if the different sites will be based on language or country though, let's assume country for this question. For example we'll have Mexico and Spain sites, both will be in Spanish but, will have different content which relates to each country.

I asked CraftCMS about this on twitter and this was [their reply](https://twitter.com/natetronn/status/487326868123967488).

Am I right to think that each site will have an install of craft, with the config/ general.php setup accordingly (in this case using domains instead of sub-folders?)

And then we'll just link to the db in it's settings on each copy of config/db.php

With that said, I'm hoping for some elaboration on this topic. Bonus points for including a multilingual, multi-domain and multi-environment for git workflow/setup in your answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have one Craft install and one DB. Do everything described in [that article](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/localization), just replace the subfolder paths with the different domains:

```
return array(
    // ...
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en' => 'http://example.com/',
        'es' => 'http://example.es/',
    ),
);
```

Then all you have to do is to configure your webhost so that it routes those domains to different `index.php` files. It should contain the info about the locale and point to Craft folder:

```
// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../../craft';

// Tell Craft to serve the Spanish site
define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'es');
```

Comment: So the various index.php files would be renamed and would live on the main domain's hosting. Then we just point the other domains to their own, said index.php files?

Comment: Yes I see no reason this shouldn't work, or you put them in different folders.

Comment: For pointing the non-main domains to their specific index.php files would you recommend doing and assuming the domain company allows it, DNS "CNAME" record change OR
DNS "A record" change or other?

Comment: @Nate sorry can't help you with that. Good luck!

Comment: No worries, I'm just fishing for as complete an answer as possible for everyone's reference. I think that's a good start, thanks!