# Is it possible to have multiple locales that use different domains instead of subfolders?

Tags: localization

Instead of:

- example.com/en
- example.com/de

I'd have:

- example.com
- example.de

Can I do this with craft? [I see this has been discussed](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/916/localization-how-do-we-manage-multilingual-multi-environment-on-multiple-doma?rq=1), but a complete solution hasn't been posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is discussed [here in the craft docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide):

There is an example with different toplevel domains.

**English and German each get their own domain**

```
craft/
public_html/            --> example.com/
    .htaccess
    index.php
public_de/              --> example.de/
    .htaccess
    index.php
```